# Why am I getting an 'Incorrect attribute value type' error when I create a variable in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm getting an `Incorrect attribute value type` when I try to create variables in TF.

I'm on this version of TF:

```
Terraform v0.14.4
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v2.70.0
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
λ terraform apply

Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main.tf line 18, in resource "aws_instance" "example":
  18:   vpc_security_group_ids = var.vpc_security_group_ids["jf-master-pd"]

Inappropriate value for attribute "vpc_security_group_ids": set of string
required.
```

This is the code block in my `main.tf` code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami                    = var.amis["us-east-1"]
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.vpc_security_group_ids["jf-master-pd"]
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_id["jf-master-pd"]
  key_name               = "jf-timd-keypair"
}
```

These are the variables that I'm trying to set in the `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "vpc_security_group_ids" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    "jf-master-pd"     = "sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0"
    "jf-master-pd-gov" = "sg-7f051404"
  }
}


variable "subnet_id" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    "jf-master-pd"     = "subnet-3ab1835d"
    "jf-master-pd-gov" = "subnet-4dad6304"
  }
}
```

The `main.tf` and `variables.tf` files are living in the same directory.

Why am I getting this error? How do I correct it?

Comment: You are supplying a string instead of a set of strings as the error message indicates. Do you want only the one security group you are accessing, or both of the ones in the Map in your variable?

Comment: I want just one. The two security groups are from different aws accounts. I want to select the correct security group based on whether it's the `'jf-master-pd` account or the `jf-master-pd-gov` account that's selected.

Answer (score 1):

I had to supply a list in the variable. That fixed the problem:

```
variable "vpc_security_group_ids" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    "jf-master-pd"     = ["sg-0333d9eaaeb3ab1b0"]
    "jf-master-pd-gov" = ["sg-7f051404"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, as vpc_security_group_ids actually expects a list as per the documentation: vpc_security_group_ids - (Optional, VPC only) A list of security group IDs to associate with.